# How do I tell apt not to install X11 & gnome dependencies cause I will use X11 forwarding?

Tags: 12.04, server, package-management, dependencies, x11

I want to run virt-manager from the server itself (so that I can use the interface management feature which is not available over ssh connection).

However, I plan to launch virt-manager over an ssh connection forwarding X11 to my laptop where I run a full Ubuntu 12.04 desktop setup.

When I run "apt-get install virt-manager" on the ubuntu 12.04 server it of course wants to add X11 server, gnome libraries, etc... but I don´t want any of those on my server.

Is there a way to tell apt never to install graphical environment related packages because I will always forward X11 to a remote client?

Comment: I think that, to use X11 forwarding, you still need a local X11 ...
(you dont need gnome, though ...)

Comment: Try [How do I get apt-get to ignore some dependencies?](http://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies) or [install a dummy package](http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/) for gnome.

Answer (score 0):

**apt-get --nodeps install PACKAGENAME**

#### However...

In order to use **ForwardX11 yes** in your **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, you must have X11 installed on both the remote and local machine.

Just like you must have an ssh client and an ssh daemon/server, you must have an X11 client and X11 server.

I hope that this helps clarify things.

Comment: sorry, but it is a really really _bad idea_ to install software with --nodeps option. You may run into big problems, especially when you want to upgrade ubuntu at a later time.

Comment: No reason to apologize.  You are making a very valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing an application which uses certain libraries, then those libraries must be installed for the application to run. It doesn't matter if you're going to run the application remotely or not.

While most of the Xorg server packages probably aren't needed, and you can remove them, you will also likely need to have at least one installed. Also, just because it is installed, doesn't mean you have to run an X session/server on your server system.